# How to use Material UI theme (pre-defined colours etc), with the react-select component?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, jss

I am trying to pull out all of the common styles used throughout an application and storing them in a stylesheet and material ui theme file - this way I can update the base styling of all input fields for example in one place.

I am using the react-select element in a component as a dropdown for a country code picker, although I cannot seem to use material ui's useStyle/makeStyles feature to call the theme's styling within the custom react-select's styling block.

Does anyone have any idea of how to use mui theme elements within the react-selects custom styling block?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the code as text? Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide the full code or an online demo? Which may help others to catch up with the problem you are facing quickly.

Comment: A `sandbox` describing the problem will be of great help to everyone.You can create from here [https://codesandbox.io/]